# boost::asio сокет принимает запрос на соединение сколько угодно раз и молчит об этом

Tags: c++, сервер, boost, tcp, asio

Есть TCP клиет-сервер. И клиент, и сервер написан мной. Сервер написан с использованием boost::asio, работает на Ubuntu и у него есть проблема над решением которой я бьюсь уже огромное количество времени. Суть в следующем: когда на стороне клиента закрывается клиентское приложение, то на стороне сервера вылетает исключение, которое можно перехватить и закрыть сокет. Но если на стороне клиента внезапно пропадает питание (что бывает довольно часто), то на стороне сервера сокет остаётся открытым. После поднятия клиента, он снова устанавливает соединение с сервером и сервер на уровне TCP его принимает! После этого клиент отправляет на сервер данные, но естественно никакого способа забрать эти данные у меня нет. Уточню, что, проблема в том что boost::asio сокет “молча” принимает новое соединение никому не чего об этом не говоря и вся система думает что всё хорошо теряя при этом данные. Как можно это обойти (т.е. либо как-то узнать, что сокет на стороне клиента был разрушен, либо как-то узнать, что от клиента поступил запрос на построение нового сокета, либо запретить сокету отвечать на такой запрос два раза подряд (Кто вообще додумался реализовать такое поведение???))?

CMAke прокт который илюстрирует как работает слушатель на сервере:

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(for_stack_overflow)
# Подключаем boost.
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)     
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED OFF)    
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system)
include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}) #
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARIES})   

find_package (Threads)

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    "main.cpp"
    )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

c++:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr int kReceiveBufferSize_ {1024};
uint8_t receive_buffer_[kReceiveBufferSize_];
boost::asio::io_service asio_service_;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket asio_socket_{asio_service_};
boost::system::error_code boost_error_code_;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(asio_service_, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 9009));
        acceptor.accept(asio_socket_);
        std::cout << "A new TCP connection was established." << std::flush << std::endl;
        // Основной цикл слушателя.
        while (true) {
            asio_socket_.wait(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_read, boost_error_code_);
            if (boost_error_code_.value() != 0) {
                std::cout << "There was a disconnection from the BS." << std::flush << std::endl;
                asio_socket_.close();
                acceptor.close();
                break;
            }
            size_t bytes_read{};
            try {
                bytes_read = asio_socket_.receive(boost::asio::buffer(receive_buffer_, kReceiveBufferSize_));
            } catch (...) {
                std::cout << "cathc one" << std::flush << std::endl;
                asio_socket_.close();
                acceptor.close();
                break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++) {
                //....
                // Код парсинга пакета.
                //....
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведенный (несамодостаточный и не собираемый) кусок наводит на мысль, что сервер рассчитан на работу только с одним клиентом, и пока тот не отвалится, обрабатывать новые соединения он не будет.

Comment: @VTT Вы совершенно правы. Я накидал этот код что бы показать какие методы в какой последовательности я вызываю, какие ексепшены ловятся т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Ну тогда а в чем собственно вопрос? Реализуйте одновременную работу с несколькими соединениями. Если клиент подразумевается только один, то при установлении нового соединение старое можно закрывать (но не ждать, что оно само отвалится).

Comment: @VTT клиентов у этого сервера всегда много. Я принял ваши замечания и написал собираемый вариант кода, сейчас добавлю пост.

Comment: Как их тут может быть много, если `asio_socket_` только один?

Comment: @VTT это просто пример, на котором можно воспроизвести проблему. Реальный код сервера я сюда постить не буду.